# Permission denied at hdfs

Tags: shell, security, hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I am new to hadoop distributed file system, I have done complete installation of hadoop single node on my machine.but after that when i am going to upload data to hdfs it give an error message `Permission Denied`.

Message from terminal with command:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /input
put: /usr/local/input-data (Permission denied)

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

After using sudo and adding hduser to sudouser:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo bin/hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /inwe
put: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="":hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

Comment: do you have access rights to the directory - are you using sudo?

Comment: Yes,after using sudo,,,,hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo bin/hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /inwe
put: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="":hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$

Comment: In my case, it was because I was trying to download files in a location in my filesystem where I did not have permissions.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I solved this problem temporary by disabling the dfs permission.By adding below property code
to conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This is the 1st thing I set in a new cluster ;-)

Comment: where is the `conf` folder?

Comment: The conf folder is the configuration of the namenode. In my case using homebrew installed hadoop however it was in  /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

Comment: How can this be the solution? It's ok for testing, not for production

Comment: @KlasMellbourn [HADOOP_ROOT]/etc/hadoop

Comment: This solution is like plug-in the ethernet cable when the wifi doesn't work :)

Answer (score 56):

I had similar situation and here is my approach which is somewhat different:

```
 HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs dfs -put /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt /
```

What you actually do is you read local file in accordance to your local permissions but when placing file on HDFS you are authenticated like user `hdfs`. You can do this with other ID (beware of real auth schemes configuration but this is usually not a case).

Advantages:

1. Permissions are kept on HDFS.
2. You don't need `sudo`.
3. You don't need actually appropriate local user 'hdfs' at all.
4. You don't need to copy anything or change permissions because of previous points.

Comment: you can replace the first hdfs by your user, example :

HADOOP_USER_NAME=your_user hdfs dfs -put /source /destination

Comment: THis is not a solution, it is a work arround. You basically say "My user do not have rights ? Lets use the superuser"...

Comment: For 2014 this was a perfect solution and even now it has its target auditory. This was clearly unlinking your HDFS users from system ones. Yes, the fact you have OS user does not give you anything on hdfs. As I said, 'other authentication methods' may be used if you want to authenticate HSDP users. Just that time nobody was able to do anything other than perimeter security. Think about it like service account for backend processes (with real users authenticated on API level or so) - in small/medium company works 100%.

Answer (score 19):

You are experiencing two separate problems here:

---

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /input put: /usr/local/input-data (Permission denied)
```

Here, the user `hduser` does not have access to the local directory `/usr/local/input-data`. That is, your local permissions are too restrictive. You should change it.

---

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo bin/hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /inwe put: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="":hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

Here, the user `root` (since you are using sudo) does not have access to the HDFS directory `/input`. As you can see: `hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x` says only `hduser` has write access. Hadoop doesn't really respect `root` as a special user.

---

To fix this, I suggest you change the permissions on the local data:

```
sudo chmod -R og+rx /usr/local/input-data/
```

Then, try the `put` command again **as hduser**.

Comment: copyFromLocal: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="":hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x                                     After changing permission above error promted.

Comment: don't do `put` as `sudo`. Do it as `hduser`.

Comment: It was group permission issue in my case, solved by chmod as suggested by @DonaldMiner.

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this problem by using following steps

```
su hdfs
hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /input
exit
```

Answer (score 5):

Start a shell as hduser (from root) and run your command

```
sudo -u hduser bash
hadoop fs -put /usr/local/input-data/ /input
```

[update]
Also note that the `hdfs` user is the super user and has all r/w privileges.

Comment: It is not required to start a shell. `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /hbase` works as well.

Comment: Good point, I assumed you would want to run multiple commands as hduser.

Answer (score 4):

**For Hadoop 3.x**, if you try to create a file on HDFS when unauthenticated (e.g. `user=dr.who`) you will get this error.

It is not recommended for systems that need to be secure, however if you'd like to disable file permissions entirely in Hadoop 3 the `hdfs-site.xml` setting has changed to:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml