# Combining HBase and HDFS results in Exception in makeDirOnFileSystem

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

**Introduction**

An attempt to combine HBase and HDFS results in the following:

```
2014-06-09 00:15:14,777 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFileSystem: Create Dir
ectory, retries exhausted
2014-06-09 00:15:14,780 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled
exception. Starting shutdown.
java.io.IOException: Exception in makeDirOnFileSystem
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFileSystem.makeDirOnFileSystem(HBaseFile
System.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFi
leSystem.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSyst
emLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSyst
em.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.j
ava:572)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:432)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
 user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/":vagrant:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPe
rmissionChecker.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPe
rmissionChecker.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermi
ssion(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(F
SNamesystem.java:4891)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(F
SNamesystem.java:4873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAcce
ss(FSNamesystem.java:4847)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FS
Namesystem.java:3192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNames
ystem.java:3156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesyst
em.java:3137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameN
odeRpcServer.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTra
nslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$Cl
ientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:4497
0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.cal
l(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1748)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1746)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteExce
ption.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteExc
eption.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSy
stem.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1915)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFileSystem.makeDirOnFileSystem(HBaseFile
System.java:129)
        ... 6 more
```

while configuration and system settings are as follows:

```
[vagrant@localhost hadoop-hdfs]$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost/
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant supergroup 1010827264 2014-06-08 19:01 hdfs://localhost/u
buntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
[vagrant@localhost hadoop-hdfs]$
```

/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hellodatanode</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

NameNode directory permissions

```
[vagrant@localhost hadoop-hdfs]$ ls -ltr /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 hbase hdfs   15 Jun  8 23:43 in_use.lock
drwxrwxrwx. 2 hbase hdfs 4096 Jun  8 23:43 current
[vagrant@localhost hadoop-hdfs]$
```

`HMaster` is able to start if `fs.defaultFS` property has been commented in `core-site.xml`

`NameNode` is listening

```
[vagrant@localhost hadoop-hdfs]$ netstat -nato | grep 50070
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070               0.0.0.0:*                   LIST
EN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 33.33.33.33:50070           33.33.33.1:57493            ESTA
BLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

and accessible by navigating to `http://33.33.33.33:50070/dfshealth.jsp`.

**Question**

How to solve `makeDirOnFileSystem` exception and let HBase connect to HDFS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to know is in this line of the stack trace:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>    user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/":vagrant:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

User `hbase` doesn't have permission to write to the HDFS root (`/`) as it is owned by `vargrant` and is set to only allow the owner to write to it.

Use `hadoop fs -chmod` to modify the permissions.

Edit:

You may also have success with creating the directory `/hbase` and setting the `hbase` user as the owner.  That way you don't have to allow `hbase` to write to the root.

Comment: After executing `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /hbase` and subsequently `sudo service hbase-master start` the HMaster is able to start again. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Executing `sudo hadoop fs -chown hbase:hbase /hbase` results in `chown: changing ownership of '/hbase': Non-super user cannot change owner`. After changing to super user by executing `sudo su` and retrying to change the ownership /hbase the same message appears. Could you indicate whether it is possible to change the ownership of `/hbase` directory using `hadoop fs -chown hbase:hbase /hbase`?

Comment: Executing `hadoop fs -mkdir /hbase` was not sufficient to solve the issue. Changing the rights of the directory using `hadoop fs -chown hbase:hbase /hbase` was required for this step as well.

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593374/permission-denied-at-hdfs) solved the permission issue. `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown hbase:hbase /hbase` works.