# CDH4 Hive Configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I am facing Permission denied error while creating HIVE table . Below is the detail description what I did .

I have 2 node clusture running on Ubuntu12.04 . I have installed CDH4.7.0 and they are up and running . 
I have installed HIVE by issuing below command . Apart from this command I did nothing for configuration as I have no idea what to do after installation:

```
sudo apt-get install hive
```

After installation I started HIVE . But when I am trying to create table I am getting below exception . I am not sure what permission I need to provide to which folder or user .

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
```

I am running HIVE query under root user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use this to resolve it :

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/warehouse/
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error is related to HDFS;you can solve this problem temporary by disabling the dfs permission.By adding below property code to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

if you want more options : [Permission denied at hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593374/permission-denied-at-hdfs)

Comment: I made the changes in hdfs-site.xml but still getting the same error while creating table in hive .

Comment: try this : sudo chmod -R og+rx /usr/local/hive/metadata

Comment: please validate the answer