# How to check using shell commands whether a spark master is alive or standby?

Tags: apache-spark

My requirements:

I want to check the status of master so that my batches can adapt to changes of master automatically, then I will change the environment variable and restart the job.

However, when I try to use

`hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn1`

to get the status,  I was told:

> Operation failed: Access denied for user xxx. Superuser privilege is required

Do I have other ways to get the status of master?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied at hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593374/permission-denied-at-hdfs)

Answer (score 0):

question closed, i found a much easier way by putting two masters together using a comma separating them. 
export MASTER=spark://master1:7077,master2:7077