# getting error while running mrjob python scripting in hadoop cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

hi i want to sort movie ratings by a python script but i am getting error

```
`[root@sandbox-hdp maria_dev]# python RatingsBreakdown.py -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar u.data
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for hadoop runner
Looking for hadoop binary in $PATH...
Found hadoop binary: /usr/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 3.1.1.3.0.1.0
Creating temp directory /tmp/RatingsBreakdown.maria_dev.20190830.233300.332634
STDERR: mkdir: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user/maria_dev"                     :maria_dev:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "RatingsBreakdown.py", line 19, in <module>
RatingsBreakdown.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 446, in run
mr_job.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 473, in execute
super(MRJob, self).execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 202, in execute
self.run_job()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 247, in run_job
return self._handle(name, path, path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/composite.py", line 118, in _han                     dle
return getattr(fs, name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 298, in mkdir
raise IOError("Could not mkdir %s" % path)
IOError: Could not mkdir hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.maria_d                     ev.20190830.233300.332634/files/wd`
```

can you plese describe what is the problem here

Comment: Try to run your command with "sudo" in the beginning. Like this "sudo python RatingsBreakdown.py ..."

Comment: no not working with sudo same output

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593374/permission-denied-at-hdfs

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these 2 references:

[Permission denied at hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593374/permission-denied-at-hdfs)

[Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:dr](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Permission-denied-user-root-access-WRITE-inode-quot-user/td-p/4943)

Answer (score 0):

i found that hortonworks take a lot of time to boot up
when i booted up correctly it worked fine
it took about 1 hour to boot